# Which legacy Windows apps run on Windows RT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-rt, windows-store-app

What legacy (desktop mode apps that previously came with Windows) run and come with on Windows RT? I tried a Surface and I tried Paint and Regedit. They seem to work just as well as their Windows 8 counterparts.

Comment: If you have access to a Surface RT it would be nice if you can compile a list and share by self answering.

Comment: @Karan - i don't.

Answer (score 1):

From [this TIME article](http://techland.time.com/2012/10/19/windows-rt-is-having-an-identity-crisis/):

> Some desktop applications are pre-installed, such as Paint, Notepad
>   and a stripped-down version of Office, but anything that doesn’t come
>   from Microsoft–stuff like iTunes, Photoshop and Google Chrome–won’t
>   run on Windows RT hardware.

[OSNews](http://www.osnews.com/story/26327) believes that Windows RT should not have even had a desktop mode at all, but the Office team was lagging behind the Windows team and was unable to build a Modern Desktop Application for Windows 8 in time for release.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can't run ANY Desktop apps on Windows RT even if they are compiled for ARM. The only allowed app is Office 2013. Buy the Surface Pro instead if you want desktop app support.

Comment: You can run calc, paint, regedit, etc.

Comment: but those are inbox tool, we talk about external 3rd party apps. They are not allowed even if you compile them for ARM.

Comment: my question is targeted at the ones that come with Windows.

Comment: they work fine. So all Inbox tools like regedit, paint, taskmgr, notepad work the way you expect it. But you can't install 3rd party desktop apps.